# Ext.Net this.Direct() not recognized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ext.net

I installed Ext.Net through Nuget, working with vs2012, .net 4.5 mvc.
following the first sample in the book on Ext.Net, there are 2 methods in the controller:
the index is actually empty, and here is the second one:

```
// GET: /DirectEventExample/Notify/
public ActionResult Notify(string message) {
     var config = new NotificationConfig
     {
        Icon = Icon.Accept,
        Title = "Working",
        Html = message
     };
     X.Msg.Notify( config ).Show();
     return this.Direct();
}
```

the last command, this.Direct()  is not recognized.
i have referenced both libs:
using Ext.Net;
using Ext.Net.MVC;

what am i missing?

Comment: Are you missing two chars 'Re' (ReDirect) ?

Comment: Does the Views/ExtNet/Index.cshtml view work for you? This is a sample view which is installed with the Ext.Net.MVC NuGet package.

Comment: this.Direct() must return a View, you might want to change it to: `return View("Index");`

Comment: after researching/googling on this, looks like the nuget package of ext.net is broken. so sadly i'm abandoning ext.net and returning to the original ext.js, hope for better luck. thanks everyone!

Comment: The both Ext.Net and Ext.Net.MVC packages should be OK. I have tested both of them, it works well for me.